# Editing a clips duration and start point on a timeline in a Final Cut XML document

Tags: finalcut

I am trying to understand Final Cut's timeline XML file (fcpxmld).  I want to be able to adjust a clips duration and where it starts on the timeline. I can't find this in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/professional_video_applications/fcpxml_reference).

In the code sample and the image from my timeline (where all videos have a frame rate of 23.976):

The first clip (Cam 1), starts at 0:00:00 and lasts 1 second. The xml doc says: duration="1001/1000s" start="13013/200s" offset="0/1s"

The second clip (Cam 2), starts at 0:01:00 and lasts 2 seconds. The xml doc says: duration="1001/500s" start="33033/500s" offset="1001/1000s"

The third clip (Cam 3), starts at 0:03:00 and lasts 3 seconds. the xml doc says: duration="3003/1000s" start="17017/250s" offset="3003/1000s"

The forth clip (Cam 1), starts at 0:06:00 and lasts the remainder of the timeline, which is over 3 minutes. The xml doc says: duration="181181/800s" start="71071/1000s" offset="3003/500s"

If I want to add a clip that starts at 0:09:10 (9 seconds and 10 frames) and last 5 seconds, how would that be expressed in the XML doc?

[image]

```
  <library>
    <event name="EDLTEST1 (Resolve)">
        <project name="EDLTEST1 (Resolve)">
            <sequence tcFormat="NDF" duration="929929/4000s" format="r0" tcStart="0/1s">
                <spine>
                    <mc-clip name="Multicam1" ref="r7" duration="1001/1000s" start="13013/200s" offset="0/1s">
                        <mc-source srcEnable="video" angleID="9ac4c512-10e0-4458-8b2e-790353594939"/>
                        <clip enabled="1" lane="1" name="IfIWasJustYurFriend_Clip41_multicam.mov" duration="5382377/24000s" start="13013/200s" offset="521521/8000s">
                            <audio ref="r8" duration="89616577/399600s" srcCh="1, 1" start="13013/200s" offset="13013/200s"/>
                        </clip>
                    </mc-clip>
                    <mc-clip name="Multicam1" ref="r7" duration="1001/500s" start="33033/500s" offset="1001/1000s">
                        <mc-source srcEnable="video" angleID="a9fa8a4c-004e-4003-bfef-04a6fdf4541f"/>
                    </mc-clip>
                    <mc-clip name="Multicam1" ref="r7" duration="3003/1000s" start="17017/250s" offset="3003/1000s">
                        <mc-source srcEnable="video" angleID="b4aacd8a-9e07-4a9f-8f63-5202a859efcd"/>
                    </mc-clip>
                    <mc-clip name="Multicam1" ref="r7" duration="181181/800s" start="71071/1000s" offset="3003/500s">
                        <mc-source srcEnable="video" angleID="9ac4c512-10e0-4458-8b2e-790353594939"/>
                    </mc-clip>
                </spine>
            </sequence>
        </project>
    </event>
</library>
```